# If else statment within a for loop

Tags: javascript, if-statement, for-loop

How do I do an If statement within the below for loop after "holmesminutes" variable reaches a certain amount e.g. 60 and then once it reaches 60 it skips one of the array items. So for example after 60 minutes the loop should be on Peacock in terms of the array items but I want it to skip it by one and put "Scarlett" for 60 minutes. I then need to do this again after 100 minutes.

```
document.write('<table id="myTable1" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="5">');
var clients = new Array("Mustard","Plum","Green","Peacock","Scarlett","White");
var indexCounter, 
    holmesminutes =0, 
    tableId1 =0;

for (var repeatCounter = 0; 
            repeatCounter < 5 && holmesminutes < 315; repeatCounter++) 
{
    for (indexCounter = 0;  holmesminutes < 315; indexCounter++) 
    {
        document.write("<tr>");
        tableId1 = tableId1 + 1;
        document.write('<td id="' + tableId1 + '">' 
                            + clients[indexCounter] + '</td>');
        document.write("<td> Holmes </td>");
        holmesminutes = holmesminutes + 15;
        document.write("<td>" + holmesminutes + "</td> </tr>");
    }
}
document.write("</table> <br>");
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Please elaborate on what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Are you asking how to add an if statement between the two `for` loops?

Comment: Yes, I am Jonanthan. I want the if statement to be like if(holmesminutes == 60;) so when the holmesminutes reaches 60 skip the item in the array and put the next one.

Answer (score 0):

It's much simpler to understand your code if your control variable is holmesminutes.

If you need to skip once after 100, just skip when it's 105.

```
indexCounter = 0;
MAX_CLIENTS = clients.length;

for (var holmesminutes = 0; holmesminutes < 315; holmesminutes += 15) 
{
    if (holmesminutes != 60 && holmesminutes != 105) {
        tableId1 = tableId1 + 1;
        document.write("<tr>");
        document.write('<td id="' + tableId1 + '">' + 
                       clients[indexCounter] + '</td>');
        document.write("<td> Holmes </td>");
        document.write("<td>" + holmesminutes + "</td> </tr>");
    }
    indexCounter += 1;
    if (indexCounter == MAX_CLIENTS) indexCounter = 0;
}
```

I'm not sure if you want to exit when all clients are displayed or want to start over. If you want to exit just change to `if (indexCounter == MAX_CLIENTS) break;`

Answer (score 0):

use `breaks` like this this;

```
<script>
    var counter = 0, full_breakpoint = 15, inner_break = 8;

    for(var a = 0; a<10; ++a){

        for(var b = 0; b<10; ++b){

            counter++;

            if(counter >= full_breakpoint) {
                console.log("full_breakpoint in <b>loop = " + counter);
                break;
            }else if(counter == inner_break){
                console.log("inner_break in <b>loop  = " + counter);
                break;
            }else console.log("no break = " + counter);

        }


        if(counter >= full_breakpoint){
            console.log("outter <a> forloop at break_point = " + counter);
            break;
        }

    }
    console.log("finish " + counter);
</script>
```

Output;

```
no break = 1 javascript.html:16
no break = 2 javascript.html:16
no break = 3 javascript.html:16
no break = 4 javascript.html:16
no break = 5 javascript.html:16
no break = 6 javascript.html:16
no break = 7 javascript.html:16
inner_break in <b>loop  = 8 javascript.html:14
no break = 9 javascript.html:16
no break = 10 javascript.html:16
no break = 11 javascript.html:16
no break = 12 javascript.html:16
no break = 13 javascript.html:16
no break = 14 javascript.html:16
full_breakpoint in <b>loop = 15 javascript.html:11
outter <a> forloop at break_point = 15 javascript.html:22
finish 15
```